# How can I redirect from one SSL domain to the one with the correct common name?

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect

all.  I've got two domains set up under apache on a single server (Linux).  I have an SSL certificate set up with a common name for the first domain (a.com), but not one for the second (b.com).

When I try to visit https: // www. b.com, it merely takes me to https: // www a.com but maintains the same URL.  Because of this, I am getting a warning message in my browser:  "This may not be the site you're looking for, yada yada yada."

Since b.com feeds out of a subdirectory of a.com, I'd like to point https: // www. b.com to https: // www a.com/b/

However, I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this.  What can I do to set this up?  Leaving http: // www. b.com the way it is is fine--it's still showing the page I want from the /b/ directory, but https: // www. b.com shows the contents of https: // www.a .com.

Additionally, when this is set up to redirect, is there any way to change the URL in the browser to reflect the redirect?  I don't want to have this warning message.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will either need to get a separate IP address for b.com or get a UC SSL certificate that includes both www.a .com and www.b .com and then set up SSL Host Headers (see the Apache section at http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-6.html). Once that is taken care of, the redirect should change the URL and won't give any errors.

Comment: I guess there's no way to do it without a lot of tweaking, then, eh?  Oh well, thanks for the info.