# Apache SSL for https://site-b.com shows site for site-a.com which as an SSL also

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

I have two SSL certificates on my server for these domains:

```
www.site-a.com
www.site-b.com
```

That means there are 8 combinations as follows:

```
site-a.com
www.site-a.com
https://site-a.com
https://www.site-a.com
.. and ..
site-b.com
www.site-b.com
https://site-b.com
https://www.site-b.com
```

So for the first two in both sites, I handle with redirects as follows in the `<VirtualHost ..>` container:

```
Redirect / https://www.site-a.com     [or site-b.com, same thing]
```

That brings me to my problem!

- https://site-a.com (which is not valid because I certified the www prefix) shows Site A indeed, albeit with a warning about the cert
- https://site-b.com **ALSO** shows Site A (with the warning screen)!!

I have two questions about this:

- Why is this happening?  Apparently Apache2 thinks that it needs to serve the first site with a cert, alphabetically, when `https://site-b.com` is requested
- How do I set a redirect so that `https://site-b.com` goes to `https://www.site-b.com`?

I can't stop the user from typing in `https://site-b.com` (though I can tell search engines it's not the preferred domain via `canonical` tags), but at minimum I'd like to not have the user see Site A's content.

Also this may or may not be related to [this link][How can I redirect from one SSL domain to the one with the correct common name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813272/how-can-i-redirect-from-one-ssl-domain-to-the-one-with-the-correct-common-name) but I am not sure.

One final question that would be relevant, I would definitely like to know if the visitor got that "Insecure, continue?" message and wonder what logs that would be found in Apache, if any specific one.

Comment: I not sure what either your Apache config files or your certificates look like. You should be aware that a single certificate can be used for multiple domain names. Just examine the certificate used for this very page and look at the all the different subject alternative names. It's very common to have site-a.com **and** www.site-a.com as alternative names in the same certificate. It's also possible to have a wildcard in the alternative names, so that site-a.com and *.site-a.com appear in the certificate. There also a technology called Server Name Identification (SNI) that is relevant here.

Comment: when I used PHP to print_r the `$_SERVER` array, I saw the SNI field, and can use that for the redirect.  I may call the SSL provider and see if there's a way to back-update the cert

Comment: There is no such thing as 'an SSL' or 'two SSLs'. You have an SSL *certificate,* or two of them.